# please provide login details for eclipse.tmatesoft.com обновление eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Здравствуйте, при обновлении eclipse выскакивает диалоговое окно: `please provide login details for eclipse.tmatesoft.com` и просят ввести логин и пароль.
я больше чем уверен что на этом сайте у меня учетной записи нет. При попытке отменить авторизацию - нажав кнопку cansel, эклипс не продолжает обновление.

Что следует делать в этом случае?

Comment: Интернет пробовали отключать на компьютере при установке? :)

Comment: @Visman я попробовал ваш совет, в итоге эклипс просто долго "тупит", результата нет.